# Counting multiple vote choices in Doctrine with createQueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a voting system, where user will be able to vote either yes, no or not sure to a given question.

These are being stored in a `voteOptions` table as `choice` with a value of either 0, 1 and 2 which is attached to a `vote` table that stores additional information. I struggling to work out how to count up the votes in a single function.

The function below counts a single `choice`, which I currently call once for each `voteOption`. I'm counting distinct users as they can appear more than once, but only their last vote counts:

```
public function countPollVotesByIsCurrentAndChoice(Poll $poll, $choice) {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
        ->leftJoin('v.voteOptions', 'vo')
        ->andWhere('v.poll = :poll')
        ->andWhere('v.isCurrentVote = :isCurrentVote')
        ->andWhere('vo.choice = :choice')
        ->setParameters(['isCurrentVote' => true, 'poll' => $poll, 'choice' => $choice])
        ->select('COUNT(DISTINCT v.user) AS vote_count')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

But I'd prefer to make a single call to get all 3 counts. I would really appreciate any advice about how best to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use COUNT() together with GROUP BY which will aggregate the choices to three possible answers and the COUNT function counts the number of records for each answer.

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT count(vo.choice) AS cnt FROM AppBundle:Vote v JOIN v.voteOptions vo WHERE ... GROUP BY vo.choice');
$result = $query->getResult();
```

This query will not return an array with Vote objects but just an array with rows that contains columnames and values. print_r() will help you

Comment: Thank you for the response. I should have mentioned the problem I was having is when the count is zero no array is returned for that choice, and I can't tell what's what.

Comment: I managed to get something working: `'SELECT count(vo.choice) AS voteCount, vo.choice AS voteValue FROM PollBundle:Vote v JOIN v.voteOptions vo WHERE v.isCurrentVote = TRUE AND v.poll = :poll GROUP BY vo.choice'`. I'm also selecting the vote option choice, that tells me which is which.